# numpy.searchsorted with more than one source

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say that I have two arrays in the form

```
a = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6]
b = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 7, 9, 4, 8, 1, 1]
```

As you can see, the above arrays are sorted, when considered `a` and `b` as columns of a super array.

Now, I want to do a searchsorted on this array. For instance, if I search for (3, 7) (a = 3 and b = 7), I should get 6.

Whenever there are duplicate values in `a`, the search should continue with values in `b`.

Is there a built-in numpy method to do it? Or what could be the efficient way to do it, assuming that I have million entries in my array.

I tried with numpy.recarray, to create one recarray with `a` and `b` and tried searching in it, but I am getting the following error.

```
TypeError: expected a readable buffer object
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: b is not sorted actually

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there. It's just that `numpy.record` (which is what I assume you used, given the error message you received) isn't really what you want; just create a one-item record array:

```
>>> a_b = numpy.rec.fromarrays((a, b))
>>> a_b
rec.array([(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 4), (3, 7), (3, 9),
       (4, 4), (4, 8), (5, 1), (6, 1)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<i8')])
>>> numpy.searchsorted(a_b, numpy.array((3, 7), dtype=a_b.dtype))
6
```

It might also be useful to know that `sort` and `argsort` sort record arrays lexically, and there is also [lexsort](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html). An example using `lexsort`:

```
>>> random_idx = numpy.random.permutation(range(12))
>>> a = numpy.array(a)[random_idx]
>>> b = numpy.array(b)[random_idx]
>>> sorted_idx = numpy.lexsort((b, a))
>>> a[sorted_idx]
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6])
>>> b[sorted_idx]
array([1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 7, 9, 4, 8, 1, 1])
```

Sorting record arrays:

```
>>> a_b = numpy.rec.fromarrays((a, b))
>>> a_b[a_b.argsort()]
rec.array([(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 4), (3, 7), (3, 9),
       (4, 4), (4, 8), (5, 1), (6, 1)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<i8')])
>>> a_b.sort()
>>> a_b
rec.array([(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 4), (3, 7), (3, 9),
       (4, 4), (4, 8), (5, 1), (6, 1)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<i8')])
```

Comment: Perfect! I just missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You could use a repeated `searchsorted` from left and right:

```
left, right = np.searchsorted(a, 3, side='left'), np.searchsorted(a, 3, side='right')
index = left + np.searchsorted(b[left:right], 7)
```

Comment: I was going to post the same.. (I prefer to use a named argument for the side it reads better imo `side='right'`.)

Comment: Very good one. But if I have more columns, the solution won't scale. By that I mean, more work to python interpreter senderly has just given the solution that I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
>>> a = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6]
>>> b = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 7, 9, 4, 8, 1, 1]
>>> Z = numpy.array(zip(a, b), dtype=[('a','int'), ('b','int')])
>>> Z.searchsorted(numpy.asarray((3,7), dtype=Z.dtype))
6
```

I think the trick might be to make sure the argument to searchsorted has the same dtype as the array. When I try `Z.searchsorted((3, 7))` I get a segfault.

Answer (score 0):

n arrays extension :

```
import numpy as np

def searchsorted_multi(*args):
    v = args[-1]
    if len(v) != len(args[:-1]):
        raise ValueError
    l, r = 0, len(args[0])
    ind = 0
    for vi, ai in zip(v, args[:-1]):
        l, r = [np.searchsorted(ai[l:r], vi, side) for side in ('left', 'right')]
        ind += l
    return ind

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6]
    b = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 7, 9, 4, 8, 1, 1]
    c = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 7, 9, 4, 8, 1, 2]

    assert(searchsorted_multi(a, b, (3, 7)) == 6)
    assert(searchsorted_multi(a, b, (3, 0)) == 5)
    assert(searchsorted_multi(a, b, c, (6, 1, 2)) == 12)
```

Comment: Fails if `7` is not present in `b`.

Comment: Indeed. Replaced my answer by another version inspired by yours :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an interesting way to do it (though it's not the most efficient way, as I believe it's O(n) rather than O(log(n)) as ecatmur's answer would be; it is, however, more compact):

```
np.searchsorted(a + 1j*b, a_val + 1j*b_val)
```

Example:

```
>>> a = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6])
>>> b = np.array([1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 7, 9, 4, 8, 1, 1])
>>> np.searchsorted(a + 1j*b, 4 + 1j*8)
9
```

Answer (score 0):

Or without numpy:

```
>>> import bisect
>>> a = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6]
>>> b = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 7, 9, 4, 8, 1, 1]
>>> bisect.bisect_left(zip(a,b), (3,7))
6
```